# Why Gather() fails if the root of every process is itself?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

Code:

```
#mpiexec  -n 2 python3  gather.py
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

a = 1
comm.barrier()
b = comm.gather(a, root=rank)
print("b:", b, rank )
comm.barrier()
```

Output should be:

> b:[1, 1], 0
>
> b:[1, 1], 1

However, program doesn't print anything and doesn't terminate. What's the reason for that and how can I achieve the desired output ?

Comment: I _think_ that _every_ process should be specifying the same root (so that they all know where to send the data).  Right now, every process is specifying themselves as the root, so they all think that they're the reciever and just sit there waiting for someone else to send them data.

Comment: @mgilson That sounds logical. Do you know how else I can achieve the desired result though ? I don't want to use AllGather() btw.

Comment: I think that depends on what the desired result _is_.  Normally, the idea is to gather all of the data on the other processes to a specified process.  Do you know which process you want to gather the data on?

Comment: I want it to be duplicated on every process.

Comment: Ahh ... then in that case, there's an [MPI_Allgather](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Allgather.html) method you could probably use.  I don't know what the `mpi4py` wrapper method is called ...

Comment: (but I would guess `MPI.Allgather` ... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All collective operations in MPI must be called by all processes in the respective communicator. Many of the parameters must be the same on all processes. The semantics of the parameters are very well documented in the [MPI standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> The argumentsroot and comm must have identical values on all
>   processes.

But then again, there is also `MPI_Allgather`, after which the entire data is available on all processes - i.e. there is no root.